# Manage coroutine sockets with a limit

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin

## Problem

I need to handle multiple client socket to peers who sends me a packet.

If they don't send me the packet until a timeout, I need to close the connection.

The problem is too many socket are launched and I run out memory on the device.

I don't know how manage a queue of waiting socket with coroutines and kotlin.

## What I have tried

I tried to fix a timeout when the peer don't send me the packet but it seems to not working.

MainActivity

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            peerClientManager = PeerClientManager.getInstance()
            peerClientManager.setPeerSocketManagerInterface(this@MainActivity)
        }
    }
}

/* this function is called when a peer wants me to connect to him */
override suspend fun onConnectToPeer(peer: Peer) {
        peerClientManager.connectToPeer(peer)
    }
}
```

PeerClientManager

```kotlin
class PeerClientManager private constructor() {
    private val tag = this.javaClass.name
    private var peers = ArrayList<Peer>()
    private lateinit var peerSocketManagerInterface: PeerSocketManagerInterface

    companion object {
        private var instance: PeerClientManager? = null

        fun getInstance(): PeerClientManager {
            if (instance == null)  // NOT thread safe!
                instance = PeerClientManager()

            return instance!!
        }
    }

    suspend fun connectToPeer(peer: Peer) {
        /* I try to wrap the socket instanciation inside this Coroutine but doesn't seems to be effective */
        /*CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            Timer().schedule(10000.toLong()) {
                /* peer.searchResults is set when the right packet is send by the peer. It's initialized to false */
                if (!peer.searchResults) {
                    launch {
                        closePeerSocket(peer.socketPeer!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            lateinit var peerSocket: PeerSocket
            peerSocket = object : PeerSocket(peer.host, peer.port) {
                override suspend fun onSocketConnected() {
                    peer.socketPeer = this
                    peers.add(peer)
                }
        }

        override suspend fun onAbstractFileSearchResult(data : ByteArray) {
                    peer.searchResults = true
                    /* process data */
                }
}
```

I got this kind of message when too many sockets are active and the packets reception are blocked

```
2020-05-12 13:28:33.638 21256-21346/fr.sercurio.saoul_seek.slsk_android I/ek.slsk_androi: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-05-12 13:28:33.644 21256-21269/fr.sercurio.saoul_seek.slsk_android I/ek.slsk_androi: Background concurrent copying GC freed 8956380(136MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 117MB/141MB, paused 532us total 229.455ms
2020-05-12 13:28:33.644 21256-21322/fr.sercurio.saoul_seek.slsk_android I/ek.slsk_androi: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 13.952ms
```

I can provide more code if necessary.

## Edit

Added the function when the right packet is received.

Comment: Maybe you could use a channel with limited amount of coroutines reading from it. They could suspend until they're available for the next connection. It's called "fan-in". You can read more about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#fan-in

Comment: I'll look at this. If that allows to know from whinch socket it's from it could be the solution. My knowledge about asynchronous programmation is a bit weak so if u could post some exemple too about this section **They could suspend until they're available for the next connection.** it will be great. thank u mate

Comment: Thx for the suggestion @marstran, after looking up this video. I understand many concepts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WGM-_MnPQA